# Regular expression to get a constant string wrapped with square brackets or quotes

Tags: regex

I need some help to create a regular expression to find a text using javascript or notepad++.

I am looking for text contains a **(Delete)** which is wrapped with square brackets or quotes as shown in the below two statements.

1. blah blah **[manikv (Delete) 4916258]** blah blah
2. blah blah **'morl20 (Delete) 180977'** blah blah

Expected results:

1. **manikv (Delete) 4916258**
2. **morl20 (Delete) 180977**

Thanks for your time and help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
.*?[\['](.*?\(Delete\).*?)[\]'].*
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fM7sA3/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `[\[\'].*\(Delete\).*[\]\']`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
/(?:\[|')([^\]']+\(Delete\)[^\]']+)(?:'|\])/g
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jJ2kB1/1)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex.

```
[['](.*?\(Delete\).*?)[\]']
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/dD5kK9/1)

Answer (score 1):

`/(\[|\')[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s\(Delete\)\s[0-9]*(\]|\')/g` should give you the matches including the quotes or the square braces. You can then filter out the first and last characters using javascript.